Efficient Net V2 M ONNX model infers significantly slower on small input
When I convert an Efficient net v2 m model from Pytorch to Onnx on differently sized inputs, I notice a strange and unexplained behavior. I was hoping to find an explanation to my observations from this community.
On my RTX 4090, the ONNX model on a 1280X1280 sized image infers within 35ms for a batch size of 1. The run time is nearly constant as I shrink down the image size to around 192X192 (with the same batch size of 1). This is understandable due to fixed overhead dominance such as initialization time, thread pool warm up, inefficient data transfer to and from the GPU, and most importantly, computational libraries are optimized for Vectorization and SIMD Instructions on a GPU.
However, what is baffling is that once I begin reducing the input image size below 192X192, run time drastically creeps up. For a 64X64 image, the run-time is >100ms with a batch size of 1. I totally understand why inference should not be any faster on smaller images, but I am failing to grasp why it would be any slower (and so much slower).
When I increase the batch size for smaller images, run-time per batch improves drastically (not just run-time per image). For a batch size of 16, inferring 192X192 images incurs 25 ms per batch (<2 ms per image) in contrast with >100ms with a batch size of 1. Again, I have no explanation to this. Fixed overheads and optimized SIMD vectorization would dictate that amortized run-time per image should improve with higher batch sizes. However, what I observe is that run-time per the entire batch improves as well.
For larger images such as 1280X1280, increasing the batch size increases run-time per batch (although sub-linearly which is totally expected - run time per image still shrinks with increasing batch size upto a certain limit, after which even run time per image increases by around 10% for even higher batch sizes that can barely fit in the GPU memory).
Running on the CPU though, processing time monotonically increases with the input size as expected.
I have already verified that the ONNX models are successfully running on the GPU when I ask it to for all inputs. In fact, for small inputs, CPU inference time is faster than on the GPU (which is understandable due to fixed I/O and other overheads)
Note: Since I set the dynamic axes as None throughout this experimentation, I have saved multiple versions of the ONNX model for the same torch model with different input sizes. Using or not using onnx-sim is hardly making an effect on the run time (less than 10-15% difference in processing speed). I run the onnx models in C++ with OrtCUDAProviderOptions as execution provider and using or not using GraphOptimizationLevel hardly makes a difference.
Outputs from the neural network are as expected for all inputs so I do not expect any errors in my code.
TL;DR My ONNX model runs faster for medium sized images than smaller images on the GPU. For smaller images, increasing the batch size results in a drastic reduction of processing time per batch (not just amortized time per image which is to be expected with SIMD parallelization).
